# Sorting so that rows with matching column do stick together

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a table with timestamped rows: say, some feed with authors:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `feed` (
`id`           INT       UNSIGNED    NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT    PRIMARY KEY,
`author`       VARCHAR(255)          NOT NULL,
`tm`           DATETIME              NOT NULL
);
```

I'd like to sort by `tm DESC` but in such a way that rows from one author do stick together.

For instance, having

```
INSERT INTO `feed` VALUES
( 5, 'peter', NOW()+1 ),
( 4, 'helen', NOW()-1 ),
( 3, 'helen', NOW()-2 ),
( 2, 'peter', NOW()-10 ),
( 1, 'peter', NOW()-11 );
```

The result set should be sorted by `tm DESC`, but all *peter* posts go first because his post is the most recent one. The next set of rows should originate from the `author` with the 2nd most recent post. And so on.

```
5 peter
2 peter
1 peter
3 helen
2 helen
```

First we sort authors by recent post, descending. Then, having this "rating", we sort the feed with authors sorted by recent post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create in line view calculating the Min Tm and then join to it.

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM   feed f 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(TM) MAXTM, 
                          author 
                   FROM   Feed 
                   GROUP  BY Author)m 
         ON f.author = m.author 
ORDER  BY m.MAXTM DESC, 
          f.author
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70d9a/13)

Comment: This moves only one author up. And what about others? :)

Comment: @o_OTync I'm not sure what you mean. The DEMO matches the output and the output from the query in [your answer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70d9a/6)

Comment: @o_OTync I think I actually did mess it up. I ordered by `MIN TM ASC` instead of `MAX TM DESC` which by luck was the same thing

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
select * 
from feed
order by 
  (select max(tm) from feed f2 where f2.author = feed.author) desc, 
  tm desc
```

This sorts first by the time of the most recent post of the author, then by tm.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `feed` 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS `rowid`,
            `author`,
            MAX(`tm`) AS `max_tm`
        FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, `feed` 
        GROUP BY `author` 
        ORDER BY `max_tm` DESC
    ) `feedsort` ON(`feed`.`author` = `feedsort`.`author`) 
ORDER BY 
    `feedsort`.`rowid` ASC, 
    `feed`.`tm` DESC;
```

This solves the problem but I'm sure there's a better solution